# AWS s3 Etag mismatch for get and put object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Here's what I'm trying to do

The target bucket is in govcloud

```
source_object = self.get_object()
target_object = self.put_object(source_object.Body)
```

And this is what happens "sometimes"

```
source.ETag != target_object.ETag
```

Though when I check the etags in the console they match, it's just the response from put_object is "sometimes" different for some reason

Comment: Are the differences with large objects?  The ETag formula operates on parts of a multi-part upload, and if that uses a different size vs the original version of the upload, then the ETag will differ as well.

Comment: When this happens which one is wrong? target.ETag or source.ETag?

Comment: the target.ETag